# Limit S3 Upload Size in P&T Assets?

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

I'm having a problem where my client keeps uploading 6MB 300PPI images and crashes the server when CE Image tries to process them. So I figured I could just go into Assets and limit the upload size for that asset source (it's an S3 source), but I didn't see any setting like that available.

Is it possible to limit the size of an upload in an external Assets source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, Kristen, Assets does not have that feature.

Comment: Feature request!

Answer (score 0):

i also had a problem regarding uploading and file upload sizes, ended up updating my php.ini file. not sure if thats the issue here but its worth a try, also this thread might help https://ellislab.com/forums/archive/viewthread/145290

Comment: Thanks for the response, although it's not a perfect solution because 1) you can't restrict upload size per upload location, and 2) if the user does exceed the max upload limit she doesn't get a notification telling her why, it just fails silently.